# How to isolate $y$ when in form $y^2 + xy$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, inverse-function

I understand how to usually isolate it but the $x$ variable is leaving me confused. Like how would you isolate $y$, when it is $3x^3 + xy - x - 2y^2 = 2$. I can't seem to find any info online.

Comment: Assume $x$ is a constant should help you here - since what sort of equation would $y$ be?

Comment: Quadratic formula, the $x$'s would be considered constants.

Comment: Sometimes you can *not* isolate. Google implicit functions.

Comment: If I was to replace every $x$ term with a $3$, how would you 'isolate' $y$ ? 

Now leave $x$ as it is, but imagine it is a constant -- you have a quadratic in $y$

Answer (score 0):

Bad news first: this is not a function in either $y$ or $x$.

What you *can* do is rearrange it in the form $a(x)y^2+b(x)y+c(x)=0$ and then use the quadratic formula; this gives two individual functions, one for the "positive" branch and one for the "negative" branch.  Taking your example:

$$\begin{align}
3x^3+xy-x-2y^2&=2\\
-2y^2+xy+3x^3-x-2&=0
\end{align}$$
Extract the "coefficients":
$$\begin{align}
a(x)&=-2\\
b(x)&=x\\
c(x)&=3x^3-x-2
\end{align}$$
And plug into the quadratic formula.
$$\begin{align}
y(x)&=\frac{-b(x)\pm\sqrt{b(x)^2-4a(x)c(x)}}{2a(x)}\\
&=\frac{-(x)\pm\sqrt{(x)^2-4(-2)(3x^3-x-2)}}{2(-2)}\\
&=\frac{-x\pm\sqrt{x^2+24x^3-8x-8}}{-4}\\
&=\frac{x\pm\sqrt{24x^3+x^2-8x-8}}{4}\\
\end{align}$$
We can then split this up based on the sign we choose for the $\pm$ before the square root.